# How to clear highlighting created by LSP function definition search in Neovim?

Tags: neovim, nvim-lspconfig, nvim.cmp

I have very recently added my first LSP configuration to my Neovim setup. This is how it looks:

```lua
local on_attach = function(_, _) 
    vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>rn', vim.lsp.buf.rename, {})
    vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>ca', vim.lsp.buf.code_action, {})
    vim.keymap.set('n', 'gd', vim.lsp.buf.definition, {})
    vim.keymap.set('n', 'gi', vim.lsp.buf.implementation, {})
    vim.keymap.set('n', 'gr', require('telescope.builtin').lsp_references, {})
    vim.keymap.set('n', 'K', vim.lsp.buf.hover, {})
end
```

Through this, I have used the `gD` shortcut (`g`, `Shift`+`d`) which highlights all the occurrences of a function. However, I have been unable to escape or clear this highlight. Can anyone help me?

I tried `:q` and `:close` but it closes the Neovim window I am working in. `Escape` does nothing and the only way out of this currently is to completely exit Neovim and reopen it.

Comment: I have solved this issue with ``:nohlsearch``, this disables the highlights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear highlighting, you need to issue the command `nohlsearch`, or the abbreviated equivalent, `noh`.

I map this command to `Ctrl`+`l` as it's the same key combination used to clear the terminal. You can remember the first letters of each key (`c` + `l`) as a mnemonic for `cl`ear (clear terminal, clear highlighting etc.).

To set this mapping, add the following line to your configuration:

```lua
vim.keymap.set({ "n" }, "<C-l>", "<cmd>noh<CR>") -- clear highlighting
```